# Property 'me' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

So I'm getting the above mentioned error on `props.me.id`. How do I resolve this?

components/OrderList.tsx

```
const USER_ORDERS_QUERY = gql`
  query USER_ORDERS_QUERY($userId: String) {
    orders(where: { user: { equals: $userId } }, orderBy: { createdAt: desc }) {
      id
      total
      createdAt
      items {
        id
        title
        price
        description
        mainDescription
        quantity
        image
      }
      user
    }
  }
`;

const userOrdersQuery = graphql(
  USER_ORDERS_QUERY,
  {
    options: props => ({
      variables: {
        userId: props.me.id,
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      pollInterval: 300
    })
  }
);

const OrderList = props => {
  const { me, user_ip, user_Agent, url, urlReferer, client, data: { orders, loading: loadingQuery, error: errorQuery, startPolling, stopPolling, subscribeToMore }} = props;

}

const ItemWithApollo = withApollo(OrderList)
export default memo(userOrdersQuery(ItemWithApollo));
```

My partial repo can be found here: https://github.com/TheoMer/next_apollo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a type for `props`.

TypeScript can't infer types for parameters automatically in many cases, and you usually need to specify them manually (if possible) or use `props: any` (if not - but avoid this if you can!).

In this case, you can just specify the `props.me.id` property, like so:

```js
options: (props: { me: { id: string } }) => ({
  // ...
```